# Jquery for filtering products

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery plugin that filter products

```html
 (function($) {

  'use strict';

  var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
    $boxes = $('.boxes [data-cat]');

  $filters.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $filters.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    var $filterColor = $this.attr('data-filter');

    if ($filterColor == 'all') {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.filter('[data-cat = "' + $filterColor + '"]')
            .addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
        });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

[data-cat] is the category
but some products belong to more than one category and the filter doesn't work with them. It is working if the category is the only one you click the filter button (if the product has 2 categories, for example, airtickets and ferry tickets clicking in airtickets filter button doest show this product at all) and it won't to show the items contain the airtickets in their category, not only the ones that contain only the airtickets

```html
<div class="cta filter">
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="all" href="#" >All</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="Airtickets" href="#" role="button">Airtickets</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="Ferry" href="#" role="button">Ferry</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can keep all categories as a comma separated string in your data attribute. Now when applying filters you can split this string and look for a match instead of directly matching the complete value of this string as you are doing currently. Also, you can add `all` category to all your products so they match that category and you won't need a separate condition for `All` filter.

Comment: I have the categories separated with comma what need to be changed in the jquery in order to do what i wont ? Thank you

Comment: i dont know javascript or jquery, so i found this plugin online and i dont know how to change things :(

Comment: wait. I'm adding my solution so you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need something like this:

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
    $boxes = $('.boxes [data-cat]');

  $filters.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $filters.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    var $filterColor = $this.attr('data-filter');
    
    if ($filterColor == 'all') {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
      $boxes.removeClass('is-animated')
        .fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          $boxes.filter(function(i,el){ 
              return el.dataset.cat.split(',').indexOf($filterColor)!==-1;
          })
            .addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
        });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta filter">
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="all" href="#" >All</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="cat1" href="#" role="button">Cat1</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="cat2" href="#" role="button">Cat2</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="cat3" href="#" role="button">Cat3</a>


  <ul class="boxes">
    <li data-cat="cat1,cat2">cat1 & cat2</li>
    <li data-cat="cat2">cat2</li>
    <li data-cat="cat3">cat3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
    $boxes = $('.boxes [data-cat]');

  $filters.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $filters.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    var $filterColor = $this.attr('data-filter');

    $boxes.each(function(index){
      var curCategories = $(this).data("cat").split(",");
      if( curCategories.indexOf( $filterColor ) === -1 ){
        // match not found
        $(this).removeClass("is-animated").fadeOut();
      }else{
        //match found
        $(this).addClass("is-animated").fadeIn();
      }
    });//each()   
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.boxes div
{
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #777;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta filter">
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="all" href="#" >All</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="Airtickets" href="#" role="button">Airtickets</a>
  <a class="blue-btn btn" data-filter="Ferry" href="#" role="button">Ferry</a>  
</div>

<div class="boxes">
 <div data-cat="Airtickets,all">Airtickets, all</div>
 <div data-cat="Airtickets,all">Airtickets, all</div>
 <div data-cat="Ferry,all">Ferry, all</div>
 <div data-cat="Airtickets,Ferry,all">Airtickets, Ferry, all</div>
 <div data-cat="all">all</div>
</div>
```